# I got an error in my flutter application 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I got error 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'. I used dio and retrofit dependencies for my service class. It show backend data in my console. But could not get data to the UI.

1.This is my service class

```
import 'package:retrofit/retrofit.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

part 'notification_service.g.dart';

@RestApi()
abstract class NotificationService {
  factory NotificationService(Dio dio, {String baseUrl}) = _NotificationService;

  @GET('/notification/getNotification/{userId}')
  Future<dynamic> getNotification(@Path('userId') String userId);
}
```

2. this is my model class

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'notifications.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Notifi {
  String notification;
  DateTime savedDate;
  bool isRead;

  Notifi(this.notification, this.savedDate, this.isRead);
  factory Notifi.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) => _$NotifiFromJson(data);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$NotifiToJson(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data that you are getting is a list not one element, so you just need convert each element .